# Remove duplicates from an array of objects based on time created

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have an array of objects and there are some duplicate objects

```
const data = [
{
    "id": "1011",
    "name": "abc",
    "Dob": "3/2/11",
    "timeCreated": "16:03:41"
},
{
    "id": "1012",
    "name": "xys",
    "Dob": "6/5/12",
    "timeCreated": "01:05:21"
},
{
    "id": "1011",
    "name": "xyz",
    "Dob": "3/2/11",
    "timeCreated": "17:03:41"
},
{
    "id": "1011",
    "name": "xyz",
    "Dob": "3/2/11",
    "timeCreated": "15:03:41"
}
]
```

I am removing duplicates in the array by using some()

```
let arr = [];
data.forEach(obj => {
  if (!arr .some(o => o.id === obj.id)) {
    arr.push({ ...obj})
  }
});
```

I need help filtering it and only keeping the latest object based off of "timeCreated"

so the data looks something like this:

```
{
    "id": "1012",
    "name": "xys",
    "Dob": "6/5/12",
    "timeCreated": "01:05:21"
},
{
    "id": "1011",
    "name": "xyz",
    "Dob": "3/2/11",
    "timeCreated": "17:03:41"
},
]
```

Comment: the date in `Dob`, doesn't count?

Comment: my actual data doesn't include `Dob` I just put it in cuz I couldn't think of anything else, but the only thing I need help is with just making sure it deletes the older date and keeps the one with the most recent date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do that :

```js
const data = 
  [ { id: '1011', name: 'abc', Dob: '3/2/11', timeCreated: '16:03:41' } 
  , { id: '1012', name: 'xys', Dob: '6/5/12', timeCreated: '01:05:21' } 
  , { id: '1011', name: 'xyz', Dob: '3/2/11', timeCreated: '17:03:41' } 
  , { id: '1011', name: 'xyz', Dob: '3/2/11', timeCreated: '15:03:41' } 
  ] 

const arr = data.reduce((result,obj)=>
  {
  let row = result.find(x=>x.id===obj.id)
  if (!row)
         result.push({...obj})
  else if (row.timeCreated < obj.timeCreated)
         Object.assign(row,obj)
  return result
  },[])

console.log( arr )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but here's a shorter, maybe faster, more efficient solution that just involves a sort and filter operation

```
let tmp=[], arr = data.sort((a, b) => +b.timeCreated.replaceAll(':', '') - +a.timeCreated.replaceAll(':', ''))
            .filter(o => (!tmp.includes(o.id) && tmp.push(o.id)));
```

**How it works:** Pretty simply actually. It first sorts the array by timeCreated descending. It does this by (on the fly) transforming the 'HH:MM:SS' string into the number HHMMSS (`+b.timeCreated.replaceAll(':', '')`), then comparing. Then it takes the sorted array and filters it through the temporary array `tmp`, which stores ids each iteration - and if the id is already in there (and we know that is the latest according to the timeCreated) we filter it out. This is all handled by the wonderfully simple ternary: `.filter(o => (!tmp.includes(o.id) && tmp.push(o.id))`, which says *if we've already seen that id, return false, otherwise make a note of it*

**Why it's cool** - For most use cases (small data sets), [there isn't a significant difference](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/2235/0/foreach-vs-reduce-vs-map-vs-filter-vs-for) between functional iterators like `map, reduce, forEach, filter, sort` - however this is thinking out of the box. Rather than build datasets and reduce them down, this smartly chops it to size first  - using only 2 operations.

```js
const data = [{ id: '1011', name: 'abc', Dob: '3/2/11', timeCreated: '16:03:41' }, { id: '1012', name: 'xys', Dob: '6/5/12', timeCreated: '01:05:21' }, { id: '1011', name: 'xyz', Dob: '3/2/11', timeCreated: '17:03:41' }, { id: '1011', name: 'xyz', Dob: '3/2/11', timeCreated: '15:03:41' }]
let tmp=[], arr = data.sort((a, b) => +b.timeCreated.replaceAll(':', '') - +a.timeCreated.replaceAll(':', '')).filter(o => (!tmp.includes(o.id) && tmp.push(o.id)));
    
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: can you please briefly explain what's happening in the `filter`?

Comment: @SamLock I updated my answer with a (slightly self-congratulatory) explanation :)